# NIC/mobo affect the speed of the USB-RJ45 Gigabit Adapter?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, network-adapter, usb-network-adapter

I need to use my gigabit fiber on my Sleekbook 15, but I'm limited to 100mbps thru the RJ45 by the laptop's NIC.

I can't upgrade my 2.4GHz RT3290 (~50mbps) wifi card with a better one because, according to HP's official repair guide, there are **just 5 WIFI cards whitelisted by HP, but NONE of this are above bgn standards**... (http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03597013.pdf)

**If my laptop's NIC's limit is 100mbps using the RJ45, will a USB Ethernet Gigabit Adapter (TP-Link UE300) work at "Gigabit" speed, connected thru the USB 3.0 (at least 3-400mbps)?**

I'm asking this because I found just confusing threads on forums and websites, saying that HP motherboards will STILL LIMIT the ethernet speed "flowing" thru as the NIC's default (100mbps in my case), **even if it's connected thru the USB3.0.**

Is this true? Can it be true?

The adapter I want to buy is the TP-Link UE300. Will a Cat6 work at "acceptable" speed on my laptop thru the USB3.0?

Also, it's somehow possible to "override" the HP's WIFI cards whitelist, to upgrade to an AC wifi card? Is it somehow posible to make work (to get accepted by the mobo) a wifi card as the "7260AC" (or similars) on a WHITELISTED minipcie?

I really need help.
Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

If you connect a USB network interface card, it will work completely independently of the onboard one.  A gigabit USB NIC will work at gigabit speeds.

As for changing the WiFi, *sometimes* they can be replaced with unlisted models, but there is no guarantee.  Unless you find someone who has successfully done it before on the same model *and* revision of your laptop, the answer is no.